# (Wordpress CSS) How to hide breadcrumbs and extra space on 404 page?

Tags: css, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'd like to hide the breadcrumbs from my 404 page only.

Tried the CSS below (found in another thread) but no cigar.

I'd also like to eliminate any white space on this page.

https://www.awesomedogtoys.com/404-2/

Thank you :-)

Tried the CSS below

```
.page-id-5063 .woocommerce-breadcrumb {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide your breadcrumbs:

```
.main-container .breadcrumbs {
    display: none !important;
 }
```

To remove the whitespace:

```
.main-container .entry-header {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Keep in mind of these 2 css, comment it properly as if you get any error elsewhere on your theme, you'll know that this css is causing it. If you are able to add an ID for that page, then just add the ID infront so this css will only affect that particular ID.

**Update 1:**

To remove the white space near the image and footer:

```
.main-container .page-content {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

There will still be some spacing, but this is not because of margin or padding but rather of your container's height.

Comment: Thank you! That worked a charm.

Is there a way I can remove the white space between the image and top of footer?

:-)

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll update my answer to remove the space between the image and the footer.

Comment: Ok i've updated my answer, if it is the correct answer, please also tick it to mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, Gosi! :-)